# Google Chrome esta renderizando mal mi código CSS y no se sí el problema es por usar VW o Flexbox o algo más

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Estoy teniendo problemas con (creo yo) Chrome, cuando renderiza ciertos elementos.

[image: previsualizacion de error en chrome]

Estoy usando casi nada de js, en realidad solo cree las variables globales y el prevent.default para las anclas y de resto, uso css puro.

Apenas estoy empezando a maquetar, pero cuando hago scroll los elementos que se suponen estan posicionados en fixed, desaparecen de la vista o presentan como errores de render, no se que puede ser, intente con z-index, pero nada, empiezo a creer que es por utilizar medidas vw o flexbox, pero pienso que puede ser otra cosa, algún erro mio, bien tonto.

Otra cosa, en internet explorer parece funcionar perfectamente, este es el pen, para revisar más a fondo el código: http://codepen.io/g3kdigital/pen/QNMdBW

Realmente no se que puede ser, aún creo que lo puedo solucionar por mi cuenta, pero sí alguien más me puede dar una mano, les agradecería mucho. Estoy usando la ultima vr de chrome, la 49.

Comment: ¿Has cambiado el codepen? Parece que funciona bien ahora

Comment: La verdad no estoy seguro sí es la solución correcta, pero al parecer este error se produce en chrome, cuando se fuerza las transformaciones 3D en este caso, quite la propiedad: perspective.

Esta solución la haye precisamente por un usuario en otro hilo, porque  le sucedió algo parecido con fixed, pero en firefox.

Hasta no estar completamente seguro de que desencadena el problema, dejo la pregunta abierta. pd: gracias por responder.

Comment: Según caniuse.com no deberias tener problema con las transformaciones 3d en google chrome: http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms3d, cambiaste algo más aparte de eso?

Comment: Lo que (creo) tratas de hacer es bastante simple y muy utilizado hoy en día. Lo mejor que puedes hacer es coger una [plantilla de ejemplo](https://html5up.net/hyperspace) y ver como manejan ellos el tema de las anclas y posiciones fijas. Utilizando como base un ejemplo funcional, probadoy testeado hasta la saciedad, es como mejor se aprende para luego readaptarlo a tus propias necesidades.

Answer (score 1):

Para salir de la ignorancia respecto al tema, he investigado un poco, logrando averiguar de fuentes oficiales la respuesta a éste comportamiento.

---

Según el borrador de [`CSS transforms`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1) de la W3C, sección `perspective-property` la propiedad `transform` "establece" un contenedor block similar a `position: relative`:

> El uso de ésta propiedad con cualquier valor diferente a `none` establece un contexto de apilamiento. También establece un contenedor block (algo similar a `position: relative`), al igual que la propiedad `transform`.

En el mismo documento, sección `transform-rendering`, establece lo siguiente:

Primer párrafo:

> Especificar un valor diferente a `none` para la propiedad `transform` **establece un nuevo sistema local de coordenadas** en el elemento al que se aplica.

Quinto párrafo:

> Cualquier valor diferente a `none` resulta en la creación de un contexto de apilamiendo y un bloque de contención. El objeto **actúa como un bloque contenedor** para los descendientes fijos (`position-fixex`).

La oración anterior deja en claro el por qué de este comportamiento: si tienes un elemento padre con alguna propiedad como `transform`, `perspective` o afines -que esté incluído en la especificación de CSS transforms- y uno o más hijos fijos, entonces **el elemento root ya no será el viewport, si no el padre**, inhabilitando así el comportamiento natural de `position: fixed`.

---

**Fuentes**

- [CSS transforms, sección perspective-property](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1#perspective-property).
- [CSS transforms, sección transform-rendering](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1#transform-rendering).

Comment: PD: sería bueno que protejan la pregunta.

Comment: *"Es un problema que no parece poder reproducirse con los datos proporcionados en la pregunta."* Sí que es reproducible. El Pen muestra claramente el problema: la `nav` (que mejor sería el header...) debe estar fija dado que tiene `position: fixed` pero al scrollear te das cuenta que no pasa así. Si quitas la propiedad `perspective` al body, verás que el inconveniente deja de suceder.

Comment: Tienes toda la razón

Answer (score 0):

¿Has probado a limpiar la caché? A mi me pasa que en Chrome aún haciendo `ctrl + F5` cuando maqueto el css parece quedarse atascado, en firefox me va bien...
Me descargué un complemento de la store llamado

> [Clear Cache](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clear-cache/cppjkneekbjaeellbfkmgnhonkkjfpdn)

y lo tengo asignado a `ctrl + R`

De momento no he vuelto a tener problemas.